# How do I delete XML nodes in VB.Net based on attribute values when I don't really know what the path will be?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, vb.net

I've been playing with LINQ in VB.Net and some other things in an attempt to delete XML nodes based on attribute values. Basically, if any node in my XML documents has an attribute of a particular value, "cats" for example, I want to delete it.

The catch is I won't really know exactly what the XML structures will look like, so I can't give a path. Also, I know some of the attributes that may contain "cats", but I don't want to hard code them if possible.

So, in other words, I don't have a set XML structure, and I want to delete ANY node that has "cats" as an attribute value, like Caption = "cats" or Title = "cats", anywhere in the node. If it has "cats", nuke it.

Is this at all possible? Or do I just need to give up on this project?

BTW, I'm trying to write the solution in VB.Net, but I am quite capable of reading and converting C# if someone happens to know how to accomplish this but can only give C# code.

Thanks a ton for any help!

Comment: Read about `selectNodes`, `ParentNode`, `RemoveNode` at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using:

- [`XDocument.Descendants()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360635.aspx) to iterate through all elements in your document.
- [`XElement.Attributes()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb292315.aspx) to loop through all attributes of an element, to see if any have a value of "cats".
- [`Extensions.Remove()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357554.aspx) to remove all elements that have an attribute value that matches.

In c# this becomes:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
var attributeValue = "cats";
doc.Descendants().Where(e => e.Attributes().Any(a => (string)a == attributeValue)).Remove();
```

And in VB.NET:

```
Dim doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString)
Dim attributeValue = "cats"
doc.Descendants().Where(Function(e) e.Attributes().Any(Function(a) CStr(a) = attributeValue)).Remove()
```

Example [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IZzjI5).

Comment: This works GREAT! Thanks so much. It was driving me crazy. :-)